# How to Display Attribute value in magento 2 using getProducts() Method

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, custom-attributes, attribute-set

When I Try to get data using below code,But return null value.

```
 $_attributeValue = $block->getProduct()->getResource()->getAttribute('weight_spices')->getFrontend()->getValue($block->getProduct());
```

My Expected Result like (100g, 1Kg,1L etc ),I have weight_spices, weight_oil Attribute to identify spices and oil weight separately.  I'm trying lots of code but not working.how can i print expected Result ?.

Comment: Did you resolve your issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is a dropdown attribute then use this:

```
$_item->getProduct()->getAttributeText('weight_spices');
```

or

```
$_item->getProduct()->getResource()->getAttributeRawValue($this->getProduct()->getId(),'weight_spices',$this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());
```

rest of the attributes could be get by this:

```
$_item->getProduct()->getWeightSpices();
```

If above code wont work for you then probably you have enabled flat table structure and you need to set "**use in product listing**" option from manage attributes

> Store -> Attributes -> Products

Edit your attribute. In **Storefront Properties** tab select **Used in Product Listing** to "**Yes**"

then check again after reindex

If you still not getting your result, then use this. (Not a good approach, but your last solution)

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_item->getProduct()->getId());
$product->getWeightSpices();
```

Comment: no changes , its returns always null value

Comment: on which file you are using this?

Comment: this is my file "app/code/Wac/DropPin/view/frontend/templates/cart/item/default.phtml"
check below code,please 
$_item = $block->getItem();
$product = $_item->getProduct();
$isVisibleProduct = $product->isVisibleInSiteVisibility();

echo '<pre>';
print_r(get_class_methods($_item->getProduct())); 

die('******************************');

Comment: answer updated. please check

Comment: Further updated my answer, brother, this is the last solution that I can give, hope it will work for you :)

Comment: anyway. thank you for your support  brother

Comment: Welcome. please check the answer last 3 lines would surely work for you

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code:

```
$weight = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('weight_spices')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
```

Answer (score 1):

I got two solutions for this issue ! , i think **1st solution is better**, because it reduce loading and  make fast response in our application last solution is the final solution but it make your application slow .Thank you for the supporters to find this final solution

**Solution 1** :
 Create a Helper Class  file and paste below code

> app/code/{vendor}/{module}/Helper/Data.php

```
<?php
namespace Wac\DropPin\Helper;


class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    protected $productRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
    ) {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    public function loadMyProduct($sku)
    {
        $productData = $this->productRepository->get($sku);
        return $productWeight = $productData->getResource()->getAttribute('weight_spices')->getFrontend()->getValue($productData) ? $productData->getResource()->getAttribute('weight_spices')->getFrontend()->getValue($productData) : $productData->getResource()->getAttribute('weight_oil')->getFrontend()->getValue($productData);

    }
}
?>
```

Then Edit default.phtml file and paste below code 'l'm simply pass the sku on my function in this section'

> app/code/{vendor}/{module}/view/frontend/templates/cart/item/default.phtml

```
  <?php
            $sku = $_item->getProduct()->getSku(); 
            $customHelper = $this->helper('Wac\DropPin\Helper\Data');
             echo $product = $customHelper->loadMyProduct($sku);
     ?>
```

Finally Run all commands

**Solution 2** :

(Not a good approach, but my last solution ) to print Product attribute values Separately  like 100g,1 Litter,1kg etc..   using Object manager

```
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $item = $this->getItem();
            $productFactory = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository');
            $productData = $productFactory->get($_item->getSku($item));
            $productHsn = $productData->getHsn();
            echo $productWeight = $productData->getResource()->getAttribute('weight_spices')->getFrontend()->getValue($productData) ? $productData->getResource()->getAttribute('weight_spices')->getFrontend()->getValue($productData) : $productData->getResource()->getAttribute('weight_oil')->getFrontend()->getValue($productData);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Please try following :-** To get custom product attribute value.

1. `$_product->getProduct()->getAttributeText('weight_spices');`
2. `$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('weight_spices')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);`
3. `$_product->getProduct()->getWeightSpices();`